# fetch related tables in swift 3

Tags: core-data, swift3, fetch

I am trying to fetch all models that belong to a brand, but when I'm trying to get the foreign key I am getting an NSSET type with some kind of address structure that have foreign key inside of that, and I am stuck with that, here is my code:

```
class func insertNew (brandDescription: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Car_Brand? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Car_Brand> = Car_Brand.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate (format: "brand = %@", brandDescription)
        if let brand = (try? context.fetch(request))?.first {
            return brand
        } else if let brand = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Car_Brand", into: context) as? Car_Brand {
            brand.brand = brandDescription
            return brand
        }
        return nil
    }
class func fetchModel (brandDescription: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [String]? {
    let Brand = Car_Brand.insertNew(brandDescription: brandDescription, inManagedObjectContext: context)
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Model> = Model.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id_model = %ld", (Brand?.id_model)!)
    request.propertiesToFetch = ["model"]
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "model", ascending: true)]
    if let preModelList = try? context.fetch(request) as [Model] {
        var modelList: [String] = []
        for preModelList in preModelList {
            modelList.append(preModelList.model!)
        }
        return modelList
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

can you help me please to understand how to fetch related tables?

Answer (score 0):

Your `fetchModel` inserts a new instance of `Car_Brand` each time you call it. It's unlikely that there are any existing models on that newly inserted instance.

P.S. They aren't "tables" in Core Data. We have entities and relationships. But thinking of Core Data as a database will set you up for lots of logic problems down the road.

Comment: thank's, only insert if don't exist, I was trying to modify the predicate to something like this, request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Car_Brand.id_model = %@",brandDescription) but is not working either, do you know where I can find some good examples to filter this way

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
class func fetchModel (brandDescription: String, inManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [String]? {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Model> = Model.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id_model.brand = %@",brandDescription)
        request.propertiesToFetch = ["model"]
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "model", ascending: true)]
        if let preModelList = try? context.fetch(request) as [Model] {
            var modelList: [String] = []
            for preModelList in preModelList {
                modelList.append(preModelList.model!)
            }
            return modelList
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html